# Does OpenVPN server require a public IP address?

Tags: openvpn

Does OpenVPN server require a public IP address so that an OpenVPN client can connect from anywhere? I mean anywhere where internet access is granted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, OpenVPN server requires a public, routable IP address and uses port 1194/UDP by default.